# C# Unexpected results from bitwise (&) expression

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, expression

I am getting unexpected results (likely due to my misuse or misunderstanding of how a bitwise (&) expression is supposed to work).  I have the following code:

```
string sbin = "10010110";   // 150 = ‭‭1001 0110‬‬

uint ival = Convert.ToUInt32(sbin, 2);
ival.Dump(); // 150 Expected Correct

uint lval = ival << 16; // Shift 16 bits left
lval.Dump(); // 9830400 - Expected Correct

string slval = Convert.ToString(lval, 2);
slval.Dump(); // 0000 0000 1001 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000 - Expected Correct

uint lrval = lval & ival; // <--- This is where I am confused (while a '+' operator works, why does the & not return the proper result?)

// expecting 0000 0000 1001 0110 0000 0000 1001 0110 (aka ‭9830550‬ (dec))
lrval.Dump(); // returns 0,
```

I am looking for an explanation as to where my logic is failing.  My end expression I am looking to accomplish is:

```
uint xpos = 150;
uint ypos = 150;
uint val = ((xpos) & ((ypos) << 16))); // result is 0, should be 9830550‬ as above)
```

Of course

```
((xpos) + ((ypos) << 16))); // Would work properly
```

However all examples I have seen (for purposes of mouse position (POINT) locations all have shown '&' in the expression)

Comment: `&` will return the bits that are set in both values. 150 and 9830400 do not have any common bits, so you get 0. You might be looking for `|`, which will return bits that are set on *either* value. Note that is not the same as addition... for ex. `1 | 1` will equal 1, as the same bits are set in both values.

Comment: You have bitwise AND and bitwise OR confused. Try using `|` instead of `&`.

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense. I understand, so then my confusion exists in the example (answer) provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279812/simulate-click-into-a-hidden-window. Showing: PostMessage ( hwndWindowTarget, WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, (pt.x ) & (( pt.y) << 16) ); // This should technically be incorrect then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the binary representation of your two numbers:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 10010110
00000000 10010110 00000000 00000000
```

So it should hopefully be pretty clear that there won't be a bit that is `1` in both numbers, so when you do a bitwise AND of these numbers it comes out to `0`.

Comment: Thank you Servy, after I read the comment from @Glorin Oakenfoot in the question (as well as your answer that made sense I should have seen that right away), Any chance you can explain why the other stack overflow (from my comment) shows usage of & then (of which there are other similar questions/answers using & in the equation as well)

Comment: @AaronMurray They might have different data, in which ANDing the values makes sense, or it could be a bug.

Comment: Yeah this all started because I was using the expression (from the other stack overflow question)and the mouse was showing at position 0, 0.  So I was breaking it down to see why it just kept returning 0 and not what I was expecting.  So I am going to go with a bug, (and I will re-review the MSDN documentation to confirm the actual representation of the data), However, I marked this as correct because it does answer the original question as asked (and which I knew but just got distracted by the 'bug' and thus confused)