# Click in minimized window

Tags: c#, vb.net, mouse, minimize

My problem is that I want to be able to simulate a click **in** a minimized window at specific coordinates. In other words, click in a hidden window without focus, not simulate a click to minimize said window. (I think my question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279812/simulate-click-into-a-hidden-window), but I am not fluent in the syntax). I am using 2017 visual studio and would prefer VB answers as to how to approach this/ what methods I should do. Thank you for the help, and please let me know if I asked this question incorrectly.

EDIT: to clarify, I would also accept c# answers

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read well ...

Comment: If you are not fluent in c++ why are saying a c++ answer is ok?  If you *are* fluent, then this is a dupe of your link.

Comment: @Plutonix I would be open to an explanation and/or some code to play around with. Do you know how to do what I want to do?

Comment: There are gobs of c# answers here.  Google your title + `c#`