# Kill application not Process - VB

Tags: vb.net, kill-process

I have a program that out of my control will bring up a message box (I didn't write or have source code)

I am trying to find out if it is possible to write a program (visual studio) that can at a set time, say every 10 minutes close all open applications(msgbox) but keep the process going? The application/task name is different to the process name.

It runs on XP and 7.

I've tried google but haven't managed to find what I'm after, all i can find is process kill. Not 100% sure on correct terminology.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (kill, application, process) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: A messagebox is **not** an application. Do you mean a _Window_?

Comment: Basically you would have to make a monitor that will browse through each open window handles, get ahold of the right one, search the desired button handle and send a click message on it. While doable this isn't trivial. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better-off writing a program that finds a current open dialog (window, messagebox, etc) and closing it.  Sending an Esc keystroke is a pretty easy approach.  Here is another SO article that talks about doing this:  [How to send a mouse click event to a hidden window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621274/how-to-send-a-mouse-click-event-to-a-hidden-window?rq=1)